# Linux: Shebang interpreter complains about encoding when run as root

Tags: linux, python, encoding, shebang

Weird phenomenon: A Python script runs as an unprivileged user but refuses to as root:

```
doprea@mlll2584:~$ python /opt/updatednsfix.py
Please retry with super-user privileges

$ sudo su
# /opt/updatednsfix.py 
bash: /opt/updatednsfix.py: /usr/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

*dos2unix* fixed it (running as root, below). Why would this only be a problem under root?

```
# dos2unix /opt/updatednsfix.py 
dos2unix: converting file /opt/updatednsfix.py to Unix format ...

# /opt/updatednsfix.py 
A record successfully updated in DNS
IPV4 PTR records successfully updated in DNS
```

Answer (score 1):

There was an additional character at the end of your shebang. `^M` means `CR` or (another notation) `\r`. It was a part of `\r\n` sequence which is a line ending sequence in DOS and Windows. `dos2unix` converted the sequence to sole `\n` which is right in Linux.

The shebang is treated as a comment when you run

```
python /opt/updatednsfix.py
```

so the additional character doesn't matter. My test indicates `python` doesn't mind `\r\n` and does its job just right. But as `root` you chose a different way to run the script:

```
/opt/updatednsfix.py
```

and in this case the shebang is being interpreted. The file `/usr/bin/python^M` is not found – hence the error.

> Why would this only be a problem under root?

It's not about `root`. The real difference was in a method you run the script: `python /opt/updatednsfix.py` vs. `/opt/updatednsfix.py`.

Comment: Crap. That was a miscopy. I updated the post to show the correct example for that case. I got the same result whether I passed it to Python or ran it directly. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @DustinOprea Your updated post still shows two different ways of invoking the script. That’s what causes the difference.